# Как будет правильно: 1. Понятие финансового менеджмента как системА управления деятельностью предприятия

Tags: орфография, грамотная-речь, грамматика, склонение

Как будет правильно:
1. Понятие финансового менеджмента как системА управления деятельностью предприятия. 2. Понятие финансового менеджмента как системЫ управления деятельностью предприятия.

Answer (score 1):

Я отвечаю на вопрос так, как он задан. Нужна ли правка, не спрашивают. Поэтому выбираю из двух вариантов грамматически правильный.

Речь идет о финансовом менеджменте как системе, а не о "понятии как системе".
Следовательно, "система" должна согласовываться в падеже с "менеджментом", а это у нас падеж родительный. 
Правильно:
***Понятие финансового менеджмента как системы управления деятельностью предприятия.***

Answer (score 0):

В первом варианте слово "понятие" оказывается лишним, во втором оно не справляется с возложенной на него функцией (подошло бы "пон**иман**ие... как системы").

Видимо, заголовке из одной части нельзя решить одновременно две задачи (ввести понятие и дать ему определение), но можно разбить заголовок на две части:

`Понятие финансового менеджмента. Финансовый менеджмент как система` `управления деятельностью предприятия.`

Answer (score 0):

Обычно говорят: предмет, задачи, базовые ПОНЯТИЯ финансового менеджмента (то есть финансовый менеджмент, как и всякая наука, включает какие-то основные/базовые понятия).

Поэтому предлагается вариант:

Финансовый менеджмент как система управления деятельностью предприятия.

Comment: Вообще-то спрашивали, как надо в представленном варианте...

Comment: Я тоже хотела сначала просто обозначить правильную грамматику, но потом мне показалось, что здесь присутствует ЛЕКСИЧЕСКАЯ ИЗБЫТОЧНОСТЬ. (Из словаря: ПОНЯТИЕ, -я; ср. 1. Мысль, отражающая существенные свойства и необходимые признаки предмета или явления. П. времени.  2. только ед. Представление о чём-л.; знание, понимание чего-л. Дать основное п. стоимости). У нас же не мысль, а ее название. Представьте, что каждому заглавию мы будем приписывать слово "понятие".

Comment: Vera, к Вм нет претензий, как роняли, так и отвечайте. Я человек простой, если спрашивают, чей окурок на плацу, я так и отвечаю, что ничей, можете брать. ))) Можно по-разному относиться, но я думаю, лучше не читать между строк, если нет уверенности, что автор этого хотел.